# Сравнение и анализ содержимого файлов

Tags: linux, bash

Имеем динамические логи, создаваемые ежечасно. Необходимо выявить 6 одинаковых пар значений  (из последних 6 логов). Например: tear11 и 092 (то, что до точки анализировать нужно, т.к. это значение меняется постоянно) Логи выглядят так:

```
/home/tar/incoming/mear2/23030107.090
/home/tar/incoming/tear11/23030107.092
/home/tar/incoming/ear10/23030107.092
```

Я так понимаю, что строки надо разбить на массивы, но не совсем понятно как быть с последними 3 цифрами. На данный момент реализован сбор содержимого последних 6 логов в один файл output.txt. В нём полный путь до самого лога и содержимое.

```
miss=$(ls -1t /var/log/miss/*.miss | head -6)
cat /dev/null > output.txt
for file in $miss; do
  echo "$file" >> output.txt
     cat "$file" >> output.txt
    echo "" >> output.txt
done
```

С помощью sed можно напечатать по отдельности tear11 и 092
Как соединить воедино данную конструкцию?

```
    echo "/home/tar/incoming/tear11/23030107.092" | sed 's/.*\/\([^/]*\)\/\([^/]*\)$/\1/'
tear11

    echo "/home/tar/incoming/tear11/23030107.092" | sed 's/.*\(...\)$/\1/'
092
```

Comment: непонятно, вам нужно `Сравнение и анализ содержимого файлов` ? или может всё же найти полные пути к файлам по заданным критериям ?

Comment: В том, то дело, что меняется. И вместо tear11 может быть другое значение. Если одинакова пара этих значений повторяется 6 раз, то тревога...

Comment: также вы пишите `Например: tear11 и 092 (то, что до точки анализировать нужно, т.к. это значение меняется постоянно)`, выходит что после точки оно не должно меняться ? но с другой стороны ниже под ответом вы пишите `Это непостоянные величины, вместо tear1 и 092 могут быть другие значения`, выходит что значения после точки тоже меняются, тогда непонятно зачем было сделан такой акцент. `В том, то дело, что меняется. И вместо tear11 может быть другое значение. ` - я имею в виду после точки а не до неё, те же 092

Comment: `Если одинакова пара этих значений повторяется 6 раз, то тревога...` - проще приведите полный пример(из шести путей) когда должна срабатывать **тревога** и когда не должна

Comment: Меняется всё кроме /home/tar/incoming, но мониторить необходимо значения которые находятся в данном пути на месте tear11 и 092. Это может быть и mear2 + 212 и ear10 + 445. Если такое сочетание повторяется 6 раз, то расценивается как авария...

Answer (score 0):

Используйте grep:

```
grep -E '.*tear1.*092' $miss
```

С переменными:

```
grep -E ".*$var1.*$var2" $miss
```

Comment: Это непостоянные величины, вместо tear1 и 092 могут быть другие значения.

Answer (score 0):

У вас всегда логи, в которых пишутся пути указанного вида (уровень вложенности каталогов от корня 4)?

И вас интересует более одного совпадения последних значений?
Если я вас правильно понял, то можно вот так вычислить все вхождения последнего элемента, больше одного в файл test.log вида:

```
/home/tar/incoming/mear2/23030107.090
/home/tar/incoming/tear11/23030107.092
/home/tar/incoming/ear10/23030107.092


$ cat test.log | cut -d "/" -f 6 | sort | uniq -c | grep -E "\s([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)\s"
```

результат:

```
  2 23030107.092
```

два вхождения для 23030107.092

Comment: Да, всегда. Мне необходимо мониторить по двум параметрам tear11 и 092 (это только пример, они могут меняться). Необходимо отслеживать чтобы одно и то же сочетание повторялось 6 раз. Тогда алерт. На данный момент главный вопрос: как красиво извлекать эти 2 переменных одной командой. Я добился этого с помощью двух команд и с помощью sed (можно посмотреть конец моего поста.)

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/tar/incoming -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" \
     |sort -n |tail -6 |cut -d " " -f 2- \
     |awk -F'[/.]' 'NR==1{z1=$(NF-2)" "$NF;N=1} NR!=1{z=$(NF-2)" "$NF;if(z1 != z) exit;N++}END{if(N==6) print "Тревога !!!"}'
```

`find` ищет все файлы в указанной папке и выводит их в виде двух составляющих, первое это unixtime последнего изменения файла и второе это путь к файлу.

`sort` сортирует по времени(первый столбец), `tail` обрезает последние шесть строк где находятся нужные нам записи, а после с помощью утилиты `cut` вырезаем первый столбец оставляя тока путь.

дале указываем `awk` разделители - косую черту(/) и точку(.), после чего запоминаем в переменную последнее и второе с конца поле, эту переменную затем последовательно сравниваем с остальными значениями и при первом же несовпадении выходим(exit), если же значения во всех шести строках совпали то по окончании работы `awk` просто печатаем "Тревога !!!"

Comment: Вот бы ещё вывести совпадающее значение в файл.

Comment: @Plastikman нужно просто поменять концовку и сделать перенаправление в файл, можно и с помощью того же `tee` чтобы вывод был и на консоль и в файл: `... }END{if(N==6) print $(NF-2),$NF}' | awk '{print systime(),$0" --> Тревога !!!"}'| tee -a alert.log` или даже так `... }END{if(N==6) print $(NF-2),$NF}' | awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),$0" --> Тревога !!!"}'| tee -a alert.log` где после обработки первого `awk` мы получим нужную пару совпадающих значений, после чего втором `awk` мы добавляем спереди время срабатывания(unixtime или свой формат), а в конце какой-то комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

В общем вот, что получилось и это работает:

```
miss=$(ls -1t /var/log/miss/*.miss | head -5)
cat /dev/null > /opt/output
for file in $miss; do
#     echo "$file" >> /opt/output
cat "$file" >> /opt/output
echo "" | grep -Ev "^$" >> /opt/output
done
sed 's/.*\/\([^\/]*\)\/[^\/]*\.\([^\/]*\)/\1 \2/' /opt/output |sort |uniq -dc |sed 's/^[ \t]*//' > /opt/channels
```

И на выходе имеем в файле /opt/channels:

```
5 mear2 090
4 tear11 092
4 ear10 092
```